# Is Isa 4:5 symbolic or literal?

Tags: isaiah

> Isa 4:5 - And the Lord will create upon every dwelling place of mount
> Zion, and upon her assemblies, a cloud and smoke by day, and the
> shining of a flaming fire by night: for upon all the glory shall be a
> defence.

I read a comment on this site, in which they believed this was symbolic, but gave no reason as to why. Is there any scriptural evidence to suggest this is symbolic or literal?

Answer (score 1):

Note the context Isa 4 and the numerous Messianic metaphors used which are highlighted below:

**1** In that day **seven women** will take hold of one man and say, “We will eat our own bread and provide our own clothes. Just let us be called by your name. Take away our disgrace!”

**2** On that day the **Branch** of the LORD will be beautiful and glorious, and the **fruit** of the land will be the pride and glory of Israel’s survivors.

**3** Whoever remains in Zion and whoever is left in Jerusalem will be called holy—
all in Jerusalem who are recorded among the living—

**4** when the Lord has **washed away** the filth of the daughters of Zion and cleansed the **bloodstains** from the **heart** of Jerusalem by a spirit of judgment and a spirit of **fire**.

**5** Then the LORD will create over all of Mount Zion and over her assemblies a cloud of smoke by day and a glowing flame of fire by night. For over all the glory there will be a **canopy**,

**6** **shelter** to give shade from the heat by day, and a refuge and hiding place from the **storm and the rain**.

Most agree this is a Messianic prophecy of the "branch", for example, Ellicott -

> V2: **The branch of the Lord** . . .—The thought of the “branch,” though
> not the Hebrew word, is the same as in Isaiah 11:1. The word itself is
> found in the Messianic prophecies of Jeremiah 23:5-6; Jeremiah 33:15;
> Zechariah 3:8; Zechariah 6:12. The two latter probably inherited both
> the thought and the word from this passage. Here, then, if we thus
> interpret the words, we have the first distinct prophecy in Isaiah of
> a personal Messiah. He is the “Branch of Jehovah,” raised up by Him,
> accepted by Him. And the appearance of that Branch has as its
> accompaniment (the poetic parallelism here being that at once of a
> resemblance and of contrast) the restoration of outward fertility.
> That thought Isaiah had inherited from Psalm 72:16; Hosea 2:21-22;
> Joel 3:18; Amos 9:13. He transmitted it to Ezekiel 34:27; Zechariah
> 9:16-17. The interpretation which takes “the branch [or growth] of the
> Lord” in its lower sense, as used collectively for “vegetation,” and,
> therefore, parallel and all but synonymous with the “fruits of the
> earth,” seems to miss the true meaning. Rabbinic exegesis may be of
> little weight, but the acceptance of the term as Messianic by Jeremiah
> and Zechariah is surely conclusive. It will be noted that the prophecy
> of the Branch (tsemach) here comes after a picture of desolation, just
> as that of the Branch (netzer) does in Isaiah 11:1. The thought seems
> applied by our Lord to Himself in John 12:24.

Thus, if the subject is a metaphor of Messiah, surrounded by numerous Hebrew metaphor, it is unlikely that we might find an isolated sentence of literalism in its midst.

Comment: +1 accurate identification of the context.

Answer (score 0):

Isa 4:

> 5 And the Lord will create upon every **dwelling place** of mount **Zion**, and upon her assemblies, a cloud and smoke by day, and the shining of a flaming fire by night: for upon all the glory shall be a defence.

If this is literal, then it has not been fulfilled yet. From the symbolic context, it is more likely that it symbolically refers to the new Jerusalem, Revelation 21:

> 1 Then I saw “a new heaven and a new earth,” for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no longer any sea. 2I saw the Holy City, the new **Jerusalem**, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride beautifully dressed for her husband. 3And I heard a loud voice from the throne saying, “Look! God’s **dwelling place** is now among the people, and he will dwell with them. They will be his people, and God himself will be with them and be their God. 4‘He will wipe every tear from their eyes. There will be no more death’ or mourning or crying or pain, for the old order of things has passed away.”

Answer (score 0):

**Is Isa 4:5 symbolic or literal?**

Isaiah 4:4-5 NET

> At that time[a] the Lord will wash the excrement[b] from Zion’s women,
> he will rinse the bloodstains from Jerusalem’s midst,[c] as he comes
> to judge and to bring devastation.[d] 5 Then the Lord will create over
> all Mount Zion[e] and over its convocations a cloud and smoke by day
> and a bright flame of fire by night;[f] indeed a canopy will accompany
> the Lord’s glorious presence.

The Lord has washed away the filth [moral decay] of the daughters of Jerusalem also called Zion, God allowed the Babylonians, "by the spirit of judgment and the spirit of burning" to do the cleansing for him and take many in exile to Babylon.

Footnotes [f] 4:5 NET Bible comments " The imagery of the cloud by day and fire by night recalls the days of Moses when a cloud and fire were tangible reminders that the Lord was guiding and protecting his people (Exod 13:21-22;14:19, 24)"

Likewise, on their return from Babylon, the cleansed Israelites will have " a canopy will accompany the Lord’s glorious presence", the Lord will protect them wherever they are, in their homes and when they gather in assemblies. [Vs 5]

> Isa 4:5 - And the Lord will create upon every dwelling place of mount
> Zion, and upon her assemblies, a cloud and smoke by day, and the
> shining of a flaming fire by night: for upon all the glory shall be a
> defense.

**It is literal,**

Zerubbabel led a remnant of Israelites from captivity in Babylon to rebuild Jerusalem and its temple, and with God's blessing, they did prosper and multiplied.

Jeremiah 23:3 NASB

> 3 “Then I Myself will gather the remnant of My flock out of all the
> countries where I have driven them, and bring them back to their
> pasture and they will be fruitful and multiply.

Ezra 2:1-2 NASB

Number of Those Returning

> 1 Now these are the [a]people of the province who came up out of the
> captivity of the exiles whom Nebuchadnezzar the king of Babylon had
> taken into exile to Babylon, and they returned to Jerusalem and Judah,
> each to his city. 2 [b]These came with Zerubbabel, Jeshua, Nehemiah,
> [c]Seraiah, [d]Reelaiah, Mordecai, Bilshan, [e]Mispar, Bigvai,
> [f]Rehum, and Baanah. This is the number of the men of the people of
> Israel: